# Why does Twitter serve every page over HTTPS (SSL)?

Tags: ssl, twitter, https

Is there a reason why a website such as Twitter serves **all** pages over HTTPS? I was under the impression that the only pages that need to be served over an encrypted channel are pages where sensitive information is being submitted or received.

Comment: Facebook & Google(Both consist of publicly available information) does too, [this page](http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/03/https-is-more-secure-so-why-isnt-the-web-using-it/) gives some reasons as to why.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have a read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every page on Twitter either:

- Is accessed when you are logged in and sending credentials in the request (and potentially receiving data that is private) *or*
- Contains a login form (that shouldn't be interfered with via a man-in-the-middle attack).

Consequently every page on the site  has the potential to be a page where sensitive information is being submitted or received.

Comment: Once a user is authenticated and logged-in, would sensitive credentials need to be sent or received again on every page request? I'm using WordPress and after reading your answer, I'm slightly worried about the admin area (`example.com/wp-admin`) because I'm currently just serving the login page `example.com/wp-login.php` over HTTPS.

Comment: The session cookie will be. That's potentially vulnerable to hijacking.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. i'm now loading everything over HTTPS if the user is logged-in.

Answer (score 2):

I do that when developing web apps. It makes securing user data much simpler, because I don't have to think about whether or not confidential information could be passed through a particular request. If there is a performance penalty, it's hasn't been bad enough to make it worth my while to start profiling. My projects have been fairly small, in terms of usage, so far.

Comment: There will be a slight performance penalty but if you have a powerful enough server it won't be too noticeable. I'm still not sure why Twitter choose to encrypt _every_ page - why don't they switch back to HTTP when HTTPS isn't necessary?

Comment: Maybe the savings in server resources is less than the cost of the developer time needed to keep track of which routes don't need to be secured?

Comment: Maybe! But a simple switch can be done in a few lines of code. It doesn't take too much effort development wise, all they'd need is to gather a list of pages or page types that need SSL.

Comment: Making the change is easy, but determining which pages should be on that list, and keeping it up to date, might not be trivial in a large site. They might consider this a premature optimization, it's not like they don't have lots of other stuff to work on. If encryption and decryption is being handled by dedicated hardware that comes for free on the motherboards of their server racks, then the extra processing time might be inconsequential compared to IO latency across the datacenter, or to query speed for Google's search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Switching between HTTP and HTTPS can be tricky to do correctly.

If any resource that is served over HTTP requires authentication, some form of authentication token (typically a session cookie) will be leaked from HTTPS to HTTP (assuming the user authentication itself is done over HTTPS).

Getting the flow of pages right so that, once that token has been used over plain HTTP, it can no longer be relied upon for anything more sensitive (which would require HTTPS) can require a lot of planning in the design of the application. (There are certainly a number of websites that don't do it properly.)

Since Twitter is a website where you're always logged on (or always have the opportunity to log on securely in the corner), it seems to make sense to use HTTPS for everything.

The main overhead in HTTPS is the SSL/TLS handshake: checking the certificates, asymmetric cryptography, ... Once the connection is established, it's all symmetric cryptography, with a much lower overhead.

You'll see a number of questions here (and other places) where people insist to have redirection rules to force plain HTTP for resources that don't need to be used securely, while forcing HTTPS for other pages. This seems misguided to me: by the time the redirection from HTTPS to HTTP happens, the handshake has already taken place. A good browser will keep the connection alive (and will be able to reuse sessions) to get multiple resources and pages, thereby keeping the overhead to a minimum, almost negligible at that point.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for the explanation. So if we take WordPress as an example (they way they do stuff is open source) - Once a user is authenticated via something like wp_set_auth_cookie through HTTPS, if they then navigate to a HTTP page whilst still logged in, the secure cookie will become insecure? If this is the case then I can see exactly why all pages need to be HTTPS - at the very least for a user who is logged-in

Comment: "Secure Cookie" is a special term, it's a flag you can set on a cookie so that it's only sent via HTTPS. However, if your cookie is used to carry your authentication in your plain HTTP usage (after secure log on), it was never a "secure cookie" in the first place, and it could be sniffed by an eavesdropper and re-used to impersonate you in this session (the attack was made popular a few years ago by [Firesheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep)). Once a cookie has been used over plain HTTP, your HTTP session could be considered as compromised, even if logging on was done over HTTPS.